# How is non-virtual instance method inheritance resolved?

Tags: c#, inheritance, compiler-construction, clr, il

Quoted from CLR via C#, it reads to me as if `call` would search for the method that is defined by a base type at runtime via CLR.

> Then `call` IL instruction is used to call an instance or virtual
>   method, you must specify a variable that refers to an object. The type
>   of the variable itself indicates which type defines the method that
>   the CLR should call. If the variable's type doesn't define the method,
>   base types are checked for a matching method.

and

> When calling a non-virtual instance method, JIT locates the type
>   object that corresponds to the type of the variable being used to make
>   the call. If the type didn't defined the method being called, JIT
>   walks down the class hierarchy toward Object looking for this method.
>   It can do this because each type object has a field in it that refers
>   to its base type. Then, JIT locates the entry in the type object's
>   method table that refers to the method being called.

However, based on the following example it seems the method inheritance is checked on compile time:

```
class A
{
    public void Foo() {}
}
class B : A {}
void Main()
{
    new B().Foo();
}
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+B..ctor
IL_0005:  call        UserQuery+A.Foo // Not B.Foo, resolved by C# complier.
```

Am I correct?

Even if I do this:

```
void Main()
{
    B x = new B();
    x.Foo();
}
IL_0000:  newobj      UserQuery+B..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // x
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // x
IL_0007:  callvirt    UserQuery+A.Foo // Not B.Foo, resolved by C# complier.
```

#### Update:

Now I understand that the resolution is static.

And I believe that the variable type that the JIT needs is actually the class specified by the metadata token.

#### Duplicate Alert

Actually it is a duplicate to [Is Richter mistaken when describing the internals of a non-virtual method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909373/is-richter-mistaken-when-describing-the-internals-of-a-non-virtual-method-call?rq=1)

Glad that there is another person who had the same question as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote speaks of the *type of the variable*, not of the *type of the object instance the variable refers to*. The variable type is statically known so all decisions are static.

The C# compiler resolves the exact method to call and encodes it into the IL. If the referenced assemblies do not change, the JIT does not have to do any method resolution by itself. The C# compiler does that because it wants to apply C# semantics, not CLR semantics.

To answer your edited-in questions:

1. The JIT cannot look at any object reference because it needs to decide statically. It looks at the type that the element on the stack has, wherever that element came from. In verifiable code this is unambiguous. The variable type does not influence method binding though (IOW your question 1 is irrelevant).
2. Yes, a method is referenced by assembly+type+method name and signature incl. return type. Very precise.

Comment: Runtime usually means "when/everytime the code runs". The JIT is only involved once before the code runs. What the JIT does is not being referred to by saying "at runtime". (The word is a little vague and ambiguous here.)

Comment: So JIT would find the method itself when compiling binary, rather than emit machine code to find it each time the method is invoked?

Comment: Yes. It will hard-code the memory address of the method at JIT time. Resolution does not matter for (repeated) execution performance.

Comment: I answered your further questions. Hope that helps.

Comment: The JIT does not rely on the type of the variable to resolve anything. All it does is typecheck that the variable matches the method that was (independently) resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Richter described jitter behavior.  A compiler doesn't have an obligation to rely on it.  The C# compiler certainly may make the jitter's job easier if it has enough type info available to reliably specify the base class method.  And it does so.

The C# compiler in fact *must* do this to implement the *base* keyword.  A base.Foo() call must use the base class if the Foo() method is virtual.  There's no reliable way for the jitter to figure this out, all it has available is the method table for the derived class.  But a Foo() override replaces the method address of the Foo() method in the base class.  Notably [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414265/why-cant-a-base-access-expression-be-dynamically-dispatched-in-c) with the *dynamic* keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, non virtual methods are resolved at compile time because you are sure about which method will be called. The same apply for static method.

On the contrary, virtual method can't be resolve until runtime